# AWS Neptune, JS, Gremlin: add Vertex with optional Edge

Tags: node.js, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Sometimes there is need to create Vertex with optional Edge.

```
g.addV('label')
.property(id, 'uniq_id_2').as('u')
.property('edge_is_needed', edgeIsNeeded)
.constant(edgeIsNeeded)
.choose(eq(true), 
  addE('connected').from('u').to(V('uniq_id_1'))
)
.select('u')
.toList()
```

This Traversal works, I just injecting boolean value with `edgeIsNeeded` variable in JS.

Is there a better way to do it in single Traversal, for example, based on previous property `edge_is_needed` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any path information / step labels for this query and no `choose()` complexity. It's just a side-effect with a simple `has()` filter:

```
g.addV('label').
    property(id, 'uniq_id_2').
    property('edge_is_needed', edgeIsNeeded).
  sideEffect(has('edge_is_needed', true).
             addE('connected').to(V('uniq_id_1')))
```